# Is it a real date

Tags: php, date

Does PHP have a function that could help find out if a date is a real date. For example `February 29, 2011` is not a real because this year February has only 28 days. This is the sort of "real date" I'm asking about. Does PHP have something to help?

Comment: A web search for "php check date", "php validate date", "php verify date" all lead straight to the manual page for PHP's function which does what you asked. Asking trivial questions that take no effort or special knowledge is just wasting others' time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use checkdate: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a combination of [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) and [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).